# What is the white, cup-shaped flower growing from these seeds?

Tags: identification, flowers

These seeds were given to me by someone who hasn't took a picture of the plant and draw it instead. It is supposed to have a white flower in the shape of a cup. Probably an annual plant in a 6b zone in Europe. The seeds have a diameter of 0.2 inch (0.5 cm).[image]

Comment: those look rather like _Capsicum_ seeds to me.  Point being that I think it will take more than an illustration of the flower to identify these.  :-(

Comment: Yes, they look like Capsicum, just a little bigger and very lush.

Comment: I dunno, @can-ned_food. I sure don't know what they are, but someone who loves that plant may very well recognize them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I love the plant although I only had the perennial relative. I've got a strong suspicion your seeds are from *Datura innoxia* or Angel's Trumpet. Belong to the same family as peppers, tomatoes and eggplants so the seeds will look similar.

Datura are annuals and the flowers point upwards (hence angel's trumpet) while closely related Brugmansia are perennial and the flowers hang down. Both are very fragrant, all the more so in the evening!

They are poisonous but then so are a great number of beloved garden plants. Just use caution if you think any pets or small children might try eating them - which I think is highly unlikely!
[Datura innoxia seeds](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Datura_inoxia_graines.JPG)

Comment: Impressive ident. Technically, *Datura innoxia* is a perennial and forms rhizomes that can be stored and overwintered in the same way as *Dahlia*. That said, growing them as annuals from seed is more common, not sure why though.

Comment: Not that impressive really but thanks. Had to be in the Solanaceae family with white trumpet shape flowers by the drawing. Datura is the only plant that fits. Just basic logic and deduction.